# How do you cause stuns/knockdowns in Tales of Berseria?

Tags: tales-of-berseria

I'm trying to figure out how to do stuns and knockdowns for Eizen's more advanced arts, but I don't know how to consistently stun or knockdown.

Any advice or mechanics that can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're question is a little vague, just asking about general stuns with a character, so I'll give you a high overview.

**Get stuns with fate/coercion/eleventh hour, spam BS which has a good AOE and invincibility on it. Use Flash Step to go to next target. Get stun. Rinse and repeat.**

Below is a setup and play-by-play from a thread to help you. Thread is linked at the bottom.

> Y: is for single combat/weakness chains. Not much to say here, the attacks all flow into each other; Last Throes is for potential Down status, however.
>
> X: is for general stun/damage. Fate has surprisingly decent range,
>   great stun, and is extremely fast. Great combo starter. Coercion has
>   great range, decent speed and good stun. Eleventh Hour causes Down,
>   and Lighthouse picks 'em up. My go to chain.
>
> B: This is where things are interesting. Flash Step is low-key
>   probably Eizen's best arte; it casts very quickly, and allows him to
>   teleport to an enemy, with a bit of invincibility upon arrival, a nice
>   good AOE, and potential stun. It's an amazing combo starter, almost as
>   good as Fate. I use this to zip around the field without having to
>   move, or go to an enemy after I finish one off. The rest there is just
>   fluff; I've changed this through the entirety of the game, put
>   whatever you want there.
>
> A: Another weakness chain, not much to say here. This set is better
>   for damage than Y, but not as good at stunning as X, however. Mostly
>   based on Earth and Wind here.
>
> LB artes are simple to explain. Y: Deceiving Pummel is one of Eizen's
>   best artes. A bit slow to start, but great range and AOE, good damage,
>   good for stunning, it's just a good arte in general. (Also looks sick
>   as f***). It's something you can spam at any given time, really, just
>   due to its range, power and AOE.
>
> X: Lighthouse is good for bringing enemies up when they're down and
>   you don't want to /can't BS them. The arte has an alright radius, and
>   it's fairly quick and spammable. Feel free to replace with Last
>   Throes, which I also had here. Last Throes is great for spamming from
>   a distance and getting knockdowns and allowing for easy BS. It's also
>   a huge hitbox, though it's narrow. Important to note, it does hit
>   behind Eizen, which is very handy.
>
> A and B: I'll explain these simply since their purpose is the same.
>   Spells that you can spam at the end of a chain, or when you have some
>   space and can use them. Hell's Gate has a huge AOE, and is Eizen's
>   only magical Fire attack. Geo Rumble is the same, except its hitbox
>   isn't quite as huge, but it hits harder and almost guarantees
>   knockdown. Both are very spammable at the end of arte chains, and you
>   have souls to spare and BSing isn't optimal/you don't want to.

There's a really good  thread [here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/167071-tales-of-berseria/75039390) that goes into my answer, and set up pictures [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kQPl.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCWNK.jpg).

Comment: This was amazingly useful.  I didn't know each button had different uses.  For how simple the system seems, there is a lot of depth to it.

Comment: Yeah it's not a simple system once you get into the heart of it! Glad I could help you out to enjoy this great game!